# How to pass parameters to a batch file from Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters

I've tried multiple iterations of the following and nothing worked.
The .bat file needs to accept 2 parameters. `$IN` and `$TIC` which are initials and ticket number.

Variables:

```
$IN = $textboxInitials.Text
$TIC = $textboxTicket.Text
```

Commands (None of these work):

```
start "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat" $IN $TIC
start "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat $IN $TIC"
start "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat" KL 562355
cmd.exe /C "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat" KL 562355
& "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat" $IN $TIC
```

This does work, but it is without parameters.

```
start "\\Path\InstallOffice.bat"
```

I am writing a program to install a bunch of programs after our standard build process so the helpdesk can pick and choose what needs installed. This is just the first command to be run, there will be a bunch after it as well, so powershell will need to wait for the .bat file to finish before moving on the the next command.

Comment: In your bat script are you referencing `%1` as $IN and `%2` as $TIC?  Does your bat script run natively if you execute it from the cmd console, bypassing the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Start-Process`. You can pass arguments with `-ArgumentList $A,$B,...`.

Additionally you can call it with `-PassThru` to receive the process object and call `WaitForExit()` on it.

Here's the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) page.

Answer (score 2):

With this small demonstration batch EchoArgs.cmd:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Cnt=0
Echo:Args=%*
:loop
If "%~1" Neq "" Set /A Cnt+=1&Echo Arg!Cnt!=%1&Shift&Goto :loop
```

This slightly revised versions of your 5 commands:

```
$IN = 'KL'
$TIC = '562355'
$Bat = ".\EchoArgs.cmd"

Clear
"--Variant 1"
start -wait -NoNewWindow $Bat -args "$IN $TIC"
"--Variant 2"
start -wait  -NoNewWindow $bat "$IN $TIC"
"--Variant 3"
start -wait  -NoNewWindow $Bat "KL 562355"
"--Variant 4"
cmd.exe /C $Bat KL 562355
"--Variant 5"
& $Bat $IN $TIC
```

I get this sample output:

```
--Variant 1
Args=KL 562355
Arg1=KL
Arg2=562355
--Variant 2
Args=KL 562355
Arg1=KL
Arg2=562355
--Variant 3
Args=KL 562355
Arg1=KL
Arg2=562355
--Variant 4
Args=KL 562355
Arg1=KL
Arg2=562355
--Variant 5
Args=KL 562355
Arg1=KL
Arg2=562355
```